# SQL include entries of join table that don't exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, sql-order-by, left-join

I have an `objects` table and `votes` table. I am currently grouping them and sorting by most recent vote:

```
SELECT objects.id, objects.name, MAX(votes.created_at) AS mv 
       FROM "objects"
       INNER JOIN "votes" ON "votes"."object_id" = "objects"."id" 
       GROUP BY objects.id, objects.name 
       ORDER BY mv DESC
```

However, this only returns the objects that have votes. I searched on SO and found answers regarding how to include results that don't exist, but I'm looking to include both those that exist and those that do not.

Is there a way to tack onto the end of the above all of the objects that don't have votes as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `LEFT JOIN`, `NULL` values are filled in where no matching rows are found - as [you found out yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360395/sql-including-entries-of-join-table-that-dont-exist/12362159#comment16600023_12360421):

> super frustrating because it works perfectly, except all of the
>   entries without votes are at the beginning!

Now, `NULL` is normally *sorted last*. But reversed with `DESC` it comes *first*. In Postgres you can use [`NULLS LAST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) to explicitly sort `NULL` to the end (since version 8.3):

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, max(v.created_at) AS lastest_vote
FROM   objects o
LEFT   JOIN votes v ON v.object_id = o.id 
GROUP  BY o.id, o.name
ORDER  BY lastest_vote DESC NULLS LAST, o.name; -- name only as tiebreaker
```

If `objects.id` is the primary key you can simplify the `GROUP BY` (in Postgres 9.1 or later):

```
GROUP  BY o.id -- primary key covers all columns of this table
```

Answer (score 1):

`INNER JOIN` basically returns results that has records present on both tables. You should then use `LEFT JOIN` because it returns all the rows from the left whether it has a matching record on the right table or not.

```
   SELECT objects.id, objects.name, MAX(votes.created_at) AS mv 
   FROM "objects"
          LEFT JOIN "votes" ON "votes"."object_id" = "objects"."id" 
   GROUP BY objects.id, objects.name 
   ORDER BY mv DESC
```

**[Visual Representation of JOINs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)**

Hope this helps. [image]

Comment: It works, but all the objects without votes are showing up above the ones with votes. How can I put the ones without votes below?

Comment: @Marc use this syntax for `ORDER BY COALESCE(MAX(votes.created_at), -1) DESC`

Comment: hmmm. it gives me this error: "COALESCE types timestamp without time zone and integer cannot be matched"

Comment: @Marc ohh maybe this will work `ORDER BY COALESCE("votes"."object_id", -1) DESC` because in this cause `"votes"."object_id"` could be null.

Comment: just sorts by ID for all entries rather than most recent vote for the ones that it exists

Comment: super frustrating because it works perfectly, except all of the entries without votes are at the beginning!

Comment: @Marc I don't know if this is supported on postgre, `ORDER BY (CASE
    WHEN "votes"."object_id" IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) DESC`

Comment: it is valid, but not sure order it is in now. there is no mention of order by vote.created_at

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN votes.organization_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, mv DESC

Comment: @JohnWoo: ["Postgre" is not a valid name](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines) and explicitly discouraged by the project. It's `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` for short.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"LEFT OUTER JOIN"` instead of using `"INNER JOIN"` in your statement.

Cheers